# copy record with all relations laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, relation

i have to copy a record from db
I am trying this

```
$new_p = $p->replicate();
   $new_p->save();
```

but Its not saved
P model has many relations i dont know how to copy all !

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the many to many relationships to the clone after saving it, something like this:

```
$new_p = $p->replicate();
$new_p->save();

$new_p->firstRelations()->attach($p->firstRelations);
$new_p->secondRelations()->attach($p->secondRelations);
```